# How to create unsavable image as a figure?

Tags: graphics

Self-explantory question. I'm looking to make an image unsavable for someone browsing a doc online in overleaf, could be jpg, png or pdf.

Comment: Impossible: they can always take a screenshot.

Comment: If you are bothered about people stealing an image, don't display it. Any other option is just deluding yourself.